# Angular Component Content Overflows over header

Tags: html, css

I am using Angular and trying to create a proper header. My content is overlapping on header as I scroll. When I tried to keep div-container class position as fixed still it gets distorted. I am trying to understand how can I keep header fixed so that the content does not overlap on header. The header code and app.component.html is as follows:

```
<div class="div-container">            
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="frame-logo">
            <img src="assets/Images/image21.svg" alt="image" class="image21" />
        </div>                 
    </div>
    <span class="text203 body1Default">
        <span class="text204">ML Platform</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.div-container {
  min-height: 7vh;
}
.frame {
  top: 0px;
  left: 24px;
  width: 688px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  border-color: transparent;
}
.frame-logo {
  margin: 0 64px 0 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: var(--dl-color-white-whiteffffff60463);
}
.text203 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 78px;
  color: var(--dl-color-blue-blue600dellblue0672cb347f1);
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  align-self: auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.text204 {
  color: rgba(6, 114, 203, 1);
  height: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 300px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.body1Default {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 300px;
  font-stretch: normal;
}
.image21 {
  width: 201px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: When you say overlapping, do you mean that as you scroll the lower content scrolls OVER the header?

Comment: yes lower content scrolls over the header

Comment: Then it sounds like a z-index problem. Try making sure your header has a higher z-index than the page content, and that should do the trick.